Netbeans build on linux fails
java version: 17.0.6
ant  version: 1.10.12
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
The build of Netbeans fails with this message:
-do-compile:
  [nb-javac] Compiling 10 source files to /media/meca1/GITHUB-NETBEANS/netbeans/platform/api.dashboard/build/classes
  [nb-javac] Ignoring source, target and bootclasspath as release has been set
  [repeat] error: release version 17 not supported
  [repeat] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
  [repeat] use --help for a list of possible options
  [nbmerge] Failed to build target: all-api.dashboard

BUILD FAILED
/media/meca1/GITHUB-NETBEANS/netbeans/nbbuild/build.xml:635: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/meca1/GITHUB-NETBEANS/netbeans/nbbuild/build.xml:630: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/meca1/GITHUB-NETBEANS/netbeans/nbbuild/build.xml:665: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/meca1/GITHUB-NETBEANS/netbeans/nbbuild/build.xml:648: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/meca1/GITHUB-NETBEANS/netbeans/nbbuild/build.xml:630: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/meca1/GITHUB-NETBEANS/netbeans/nbbuild/build.xml:677: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/media/meca1/GITHUB-NETBEANS/netbeans/nbbuild/templates/common.xml:208: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details

First attempt was using the java jdk 17.
Tryied to change the java version to an older one.
Even if the netbeans documentation says 17 is OK.
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11
The issue is the same.

The "error: release version 17 not supported" suggests that an older version than Java 17 is actually getting used.

Examine the Ant build.xml (and/or /media/meca1/GITHUB-NETBEANS/netbeans/nbbuild/templates/common.xml)

You definitely need Java 17 as the author states: https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/7239#issuecomment-2045328313

Install an LTS release of the Java Development Kit. (JDK 11+)

@g00se This information does not apply here because it deals with NetBeans 21. The failing code was introduced two weeks ago and is therefore only available in the nightlies yet. And this will need (just like Netbeans 22 in general) Java 17 (see my link above).

@JoachimRohde I see, so that info I quoted is out of date?

@MarkRotteveel your comment helped . As JAVA_HOME was correctly set, environment PATH was using version 11.
Fixed the PATH and the compilation succeed

Setting JAVA_HOME variable in not sufficient.
The PATH environment variable must also point jdk 17.
After fixing this the compilation succeed.
